# ¿Cómo cambiar la imagen en modo celular o xs en Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Actualmente tengo una imagen que se muestra arriba del titulo:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <figure>
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img src="..." alt="4x3 Image" class="img-responsive">
                <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <header class="col-md-12 ">
        <a href="#">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </a>
    </header>    
</div>
```

Pero lo que quiero, es que cuando cambie a modo celular xs, la imagen se muestre a la derecha del title, por ejemplo para el titulo quede col-xs-9 y la imagen quede con col-xs-3.

¿Cómo se podrá hacer?

Se les agradece su ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto sí debería funcionar:

```
<div class="col-xs-9 pull-right col-sm-12">
<div>

<header class="col-xs-3 col-sm-12">
</header>
```

Comment: gracias @BetaM por tu comentario, ya edité una y borré la otra

Comment: Excelente...funciono