# ¿Como cambiar la posición de la imagen en modo celular o xs en boostrap 4?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4, bootstrap

Deseo que cuando cambie a modo celular xs, la imagen se muestre a la derecha del title. por ejemplo para el titulo quede col-xs-9 y la imagen quede con col-xs-3. Anteriormente hice esta pregunta para boostrap 3, lo cual la solución de ejemplo es la siguiente:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 pull-right col-md-12">
   <img src="@Url.Content(rutafoto)" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100px;" />
<div>

<header class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-12 ">
        <a href="#">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </a>
</header>
```

Dando como solución la clase pull-right,

Pero en este caso, para boostrap4, he probado con el float-right y el float-sm-right reemplazando el pull-right, pero no funciona.
¿Como podría solucionarlo?¿Podría haber algun ejemplo?

-------parte nueva editada---

Así como quiero que se vea en pantalla grande o en pc
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y así como deseo que se vea en celular:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---fin parte editada---

Les dejo el link de la pregunta anterior para boostrap 3.

[¿Como cambiar la imagen en modo celular o xs en boostrap 3?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/378830/como-cambiar-la-imagen-en-modo-celular-o-xs-en-boostrap-3/378848#378848)

Answer (score 1):

Tendras una representacion grafica de lo que se busca, te comento pues probando el codigo proporcionado, funciona igual en bootstrap 3 y 4. aunque talves por lo que comentas, te sirva la propiedad order

[Documentacion bootstrap4 order](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering)

De la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-3 order-1 order-md-2">
    Este contenedor se mueve al princpio (izquierda) si es menor a md y al final (derecha) si es md o mayor
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-9 order-2 order-md-1">
    Este contenedor se mueve al final (derecha) si es menor a md y al principio (izquierda) si es md o mayor
  </div>
</div>
```

No se si sea el comportamiento que buscas, o si requieres otro, realmente serviria una imagen o diagrama, pero espero que esto sirva

---

ACTUALIZACION:

Gracias por la informacion, incluyendo la informacion que das, es posible que esta sea tu solucion, suponiendo que usas bootstrap4 y que estan en un row ambos

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-12 order-2 order-md-1">
       <img src="@Url.Content(rutafoto)" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100px;" />
    </div>

    <header class="col-8 col-sm-9 col-md-12 order-1 order-md-2 ">
            <a href="#">
                <h2>Title</h2>
            </a>
    </header>

</div>
```

Saludos

---

Muestro fuente en codepen

[PRUEBA EN CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/overvoiplatam/pen/GRZowZw)

y adicionalmente en

```
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-12 order-2 order-md-1">
   <img src="@Url.Content(rutafoto)" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100px;" />
<div>
```

Esta mal cerrado el div

Comment: Hola @Jesus Ramon Rocha Velazquez, gracias por responder, pero la solución que me diste no resultó, pero edite la pregunta y puse en ejemplo de como deseo que se vea la foto.

Comment: tambien especifique mas los col-

Comment: Gracias, ya actualice la respuesta, espero que sea de utilidad, saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, esa es la solución